# Coalesce - ing an array of bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in which I grab a bunch of data and aggregate it into and array with a group by.
Sample query:

```
SELECT name, array_agg(ot.userid) as other_users 
FROM room 
LEFT JOIN other_table as ot ON someCondition
WHERE room.id = $1      -- some room id
GROUP BY name

ot.userid is a bigint type here
```

Now, if a condition is not met, the the other_users column comes back as an array with null in it.

```
// [null]
```

Not a value I want, I would like to have an empty array return instead

```
// []
```

Is there a way to do that?

I was looking to so something like `COALESCE`

but that doesn't work:

```
-- tried to make it return 0 instead of array
SELECT name, COALESCE(array_agg(ot.userid), 0) as other_users 
FROM room 
LEFT JOIN other_table as ot ON someCondition
WHERE room.id = $1      -- some room id
GROUP BY name
```

Error I get:

```
[error: COALESCE types bigint[] and integer cannot be matched]
```

**How can I send back an empty array without 'null' inside it?**

Comment: did you try `COALESCE(array_agg(ot.userid), cast(0 as bigint))`?

Comment: No, I have not. I am mainly looking for how to send an empty array rather than a 0. I just threw zero in there to give a sample of coalesce. But thanks for the tip. It will come in handy if I can't do other things.

Comment: Well, the error that is returned in OP is that he cannot coalesce a bigint (ot.userid) with an int (0). So basically the error message is more confusing than anythign else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
case
  when array_agg(ot.userid) = array_agg(null::bigint) then array[]::bigint[]
  else array_agg(ot.userid)
end
```

Or:

```
case
  when array_agg(ot.userid) = array[null]::bigint[] then array[]::bigint[]
  else array_agg(ot.userid)
end
```